# JPQL order by one of ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have following entities:

```
Article
| 
+- @Id long id
|
+- @ElementCollection Map<Language, Translation> translations

Translation
|
+- @Column String name
```

What I would like to achieve is to fetch a list of Articles, ordered by name in given Language.

Something like:

```
SELECT a FROM Article a 
JOIN a.translations t WHERE t.language = ? 
ORDER BY t.name
```

The problem is that when using `t.language` throws "could not resolve property" exception, even though the `language` column exists in the Translations database table.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not supported by Hibernate. I would simply make Translation an entity rather than an embedded, and include a language field in the Translation entity.

The mapping would be

```
 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
 @MapKey(name = "language")
 private Map<Language, Translation> translations;
```

The association could also be bidirectional, and your query could then be much more logical and less dangerous, because it could return translations rather than articles:

```
select t from Translation t 
inner join fetch t.article 
where t.language = :language 
order by t.name
```

Comment: Thank you! Isn't there any solution without changing the Embeddable for Entity? It adds millions of values (IDs for translations) which I will never use and I am bit worried about performance.

Comment: How does it add any value? The database schema should (or at least could) be identical. A surrogate primary key usually improves the performance, rather than decreasing it.

Comment: There is added ID column. For millions of rows it is significant. But I understand that there is no other option.

Comment: You have another option: keep the schema as it is right now, and use the existing language-articleId pair as the composite ID of your Translation entity.

Comment: The rules are explained here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819. You'll need a MapsId annotation to say that the ManyToOne Article field maps to the same column as the articleId field.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I am having troubles persisting such Entities - when I persist the Article, I am having null values of article_id in Translations. I can't find a way to reference the article_id in Translation to the id in Article. At the moment of persisting it, the ID of the Article is not yet generated, so it cannot be set to the Translation. How can I tell Hibernate to reference the two? The problem is well described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954357/persisting-onetomany-relations-with-joincolumn-and-mapkeycolumn