# Persisting @OneToMany relations with @JoinColumn and @MapKeyColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="embed_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Map<Language, Locale> locales;

    Article() {
        locales.put(Language.CS, new Locale());
        locales.put(Language.EN, new Locale());
    }
}

@Entity
Locale {
    @Id
    private Long embed_id;

    @Id
    private Language language;

    @Column(length = 256)
    private String name;
}
```

Thanks to the constructor, I can make sure, that once an `Article` is instantiated, two `Locales` (with CascadeType.ALL) are associated with it.

The problem comes when I try to persist such entity - I am getting:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: 
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated 
      with the session: org...Locale#org...Locale@2bfdsc64
```

The problem is that neither `embed_id`, nor `language` have assigned values from the Article when persisting and Hibernate does not associate them after persisting Article. How can this be done?

**Edit 1:**

I checked that when the `embed_id` and `language` are set manually, everything works correctly. I just need to tell Hibernate, to set the value of @`JoinColumn` and @`MapKeyColumn` according to the @`OneToMany` relation.

**Edit 2:**

The problem with MapKeyColumn has an easy solution:

```
 public void addLocale(Language l, Locale locale) {
      locale.setLanguage(l);
      this.locales.put(l);
 }
```

But I am still unable to tell hibernate to associate the Locale.embed_id from Article.id.

**Edit 3:**

I can see that the ID of article is properly generated, but then it is not put in the locale:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - 
    Generated identifier: 87, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator
DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - 
    Generated identifier: component[language,embedId]{language=0, embedId=null}, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - 
    Generated identifier: component[language,embedId]{language=1, embedId=null}, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the anwswer! The trick was to create Setter on Article and add Access to id as follows:

```
@Id
@Getter
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.getLocale(Language.CS).setEmbedId(id);
    this.getLocale(Language.EN).setEmbedId(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is, that you want to persist two empty locales. And because you don't use a generator for the id-fields, the locales have the same (empty) primary key and therefore can't be persisted.

Comment: I know, but how can I tell hibernate to associate them with the key of the Map? It is not only language - because when I set it manually, I am getting: `null value in column "embed_id" violates not-null constraint;`

Comment: But `embed_id` is not necessarily unique (because you combine it with `language` to achieve uniqueness). Probably a non-unique key can't be the (unique) key of a `map`?

Comment: It is unique with combination with language. The primary key is `embed_id,language` combination.

Comment: I just need to find out how to tell HIbernate to update those fields.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, only the combination is unique, not `embed_id` alone, and maybe `embed_id` can't be the key of a `map`, because it's not unique. You know what i mean?

Comment: But embed_id is not the key of the map, it is language. Embed_id is a JoinColumn. When I set all the values manually, it works all correctly.

Comment: Yeah right, my bad, I meant `language` instead of `embed_id`.
But then I don't know how to achieve what you are describing, sry...

Comment: Thanks anyway, I gave you +1.